# Adapter addAll method for flatten object in NGRX

Tags: angular, adapter, ngrx

I would like to know what is the proper approach for handling Entity Adapter when response from backend is a flatten object like this :

```
"languages": {
        "en": {
            "iso": "en",
            "name": "English",
            "nativeName": "English"
        }
   }
```

Previously it was classic array with id (as iso) :

```
"languages": [
            { 
                "iso": "en",
                "name": "English",
                "nativeName": "English"
            }
       ]
```

so I easily used:

```
languagesAdapter.addAll(action.languages, {
            ...state,
        })
```

How to handle Entity Adapter addAll() in case of flatten object?

Answer (score 2):

Possible way to solve it is to create answer based on response:

```
this.http.get(`URL ADDRESS`).pipe(map(res=> {
            return {
                ...res,
                languages : Object.values(res.languages)
            }
        }))
```

That way we are having a lot of useful methods from EntityAdapter for free in such a case :)